# how to create loop function to the local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I create input values are stored in local storage, with individual script, I dont know how to combined the function, I need to single script of the function. please guide me, thanks in advance.

```js
function action() {
  window.localStorage['header1'] = document.getElementById('header1').value;
  window.localStorage['header2'] = document.getElementById('header2').value;
  window.localStorage['header3'] = document.getElementById('header3').value;
  window.localStorage['header4'] = document.getElementById('header4').value;
}

function action2() {
  document.getElementById('header1').value = window.localStorage['header1'];
  document.getElementById('header2').value = window.localStorage['header2'];
  document.getElementById('header3').value = window.localStorage['header3'];
  document.getElementById('header4').value = window.localStorage['header4'];

}
```

```html
<body onload="action2()">
  <input type="text" id="header1" name="header1" value="name1">
  <input type="text" id="header2" name="header2" value="name2">
  <input type="text" id="header3" name="header3" value="name3">
  <input type="text" id="header4" name="header4" value="name4">

  <p><button onclick="action()" type="button">Save me!</button></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine the function you could have an argument of `type` as to specify whether you want to use the DOM of local storage.

Then you can use a for loop to loop all your elements so you don't repeat yourself.

```
function action(type) {
  for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if(type === "element") {
      document.getElementById('header' + i).value = window.localStorage['header' +i];
    } else if(type === "storage") { 
      window.localStorage['header' +i] = document.getElementById('header' +i).value;
    }
  }
}

action("storage"); // equivalent to: action()
action("element"); // equivalent to: action2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit confused, are you looking for this? I haven't tested this either...

```
var len = 4;    

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    window.localStorage['header'+ i] = document.getElementById('header' + i).value;
}
```

You are probably better off storing it all in one object and adding that to localstorage like this...

```
var len = 4;
var localObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    localObj['header'+ i] = document.getElementById('header' + i).value;
}

window.localStorage['headers'] = JSON.stringify(localObj);
```

Then you can retrieve it like below, which will give you an object, headers.headers1 etc...

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('headers'));
```

Comment: No problems :-)